# Testing $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {e^{nx} \cos(nx)} \; , \; x \in (-\infty,-1]$ for uniform convergence

Tags: calculus

Is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {e^{nx} \cos(nx)} \; , \; x \in (-\infty,-1]$$
uniformly convergent?

---

I said the following:

$e^{nx}\cos(nx) \leq e^{nx} \sim \frac{1}{e^{n|x|}} $ because $\cos(nx) \leq 1$ and $x< 0$ for all $x\in(-\infty,-1]$

And we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{e^{n|x|}}}$ is convergent.

Is what I did correct?

Comment: You should put absolute values: $$|e^{nx}\cos(nx)|\leq e^{nx}$$ since $\cos(nx)$ can be negative.

Comment: But what you've proven is just that the series is absolutely convergent. Uniformly convergence follows since $e^{xn}\leq e^{-n}$.

Comment: Thomas, thank you so much. I totally forgot about absolute values and that uniformly convergence needs to be unconditional of $x$.
Excuse me, I'm new to Calculus II.
So, adding the two things you said, makes my solution (almost) right?

Comment: Depends on what theorems you have - definitely that $e^{nx}\leq e^{-n}$ is necessary, but you might have to show how this implies uniform convergence, if you don't already have a theorem for that.

Comment: We have Weierstrass for it, no?

Comment: Yes, that will do. Just wasn't sure you had gotten to that one (and couldn't recall the name.)

Comment: Haha no worries.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have proven is that the series is absolutely convergent, not that it is uniformly convergent. For uniform convergence, you need to use that $e^{nx}\leq e^{-n}$.

Indeed, the series converges absolutely for $x\in(-\infty,0)$, but it doesn't converge uniformly in that interval.

Comment: Wait. Why does it not converge uniformly? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{e^n}}$ is convergent. No? So according to Weierstrass, it is uniformly convergent... or am I not getting something?

Comment: It doesn't converge uniformly on $(-\infty,0)$ - the bound only works for $(-\infty,-1)$. Note the different interval.  My point was, merely showing absolute convergence was not enough.

Comment: Oh. Thanks.
Can you please explain more why it does not converge uniformly on $(-\infty, 0)$ ?

Comment: Well, that wasn't meant as a proof,just an assertion - proving something isn't uniformly convergent is a little harder. The sum has a closed formula, and we can show that it is unbounded on $(-\infty,0)$. But the rest of that proof is too long for this question, really.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway. Thanks alot for all your explanations! You've been a great help.